# Show that $I$ is an interval iff any function $f:I\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, interval-arithmetic

Let $I\in R$ be a nonemplty set. Show that $I$ is an interval iff any function $f:I\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is continuous.

I've no idea how to handle this problem. Thanks in advvance to anyone who comes up with a step - solution.

Comment: Do you mean to say that every $f:I\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ which is continuous is constant? I believe the statement you've given is false.

Comment: Are you sure? Any function $\{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ is continuous. The correct statement is “$I$ is an interval if and only if every continuous function $f\colon I\to\{0,1\}$ is constant”.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Looking at the source code, I edited this question.  However, since edits should preserve the idea of OP, I leave "continuous" alone.

Comment: What do you mean by "Let $I\in R$ be a nonempty set"? Is $R$ the real numbers? If so this doesn't make much sense.  I'm guessing you mean "Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty."

Comment: Doesn't seem in the least bit true.  Let f:[0,1]->{0,1} via f(x) = 0 if x is rational and f(x) = 1 if x is irrational.  That's not continuous.  In fact only constant functions would be.

Comment: In fact you're asking to prove a contradiction. A non-very-standard yet known definition of non connected space $\;X\;$ is that for which there exists a continuous *onto* function $\;X\to\{0,1\}\;$ , where the last set has the inherited topology from the reals (i.e., it is discrete). Yet a subset of the real line is connected iff it is an interval...

Comment: I think you should edit : Change $I\in R$ to $I\subset R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be true.

Let $I$ be any set, interval or not, then $f(x) = 0$ is a continuous function whether or not $I$ is an interval.  And $I$ = $A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are separated then if $f(A) = 0$ and $f(B) = 1$, $f$ is continuous.

Likewise on an interval one can easily find an non-continuous function to $\{0,1\}$.  Simply map any arbitrary points to $0$ and all the rest to $1$.  Say, $I = [0,1]; f(1) = 1;f(x) = 0$ if $x<1$ .

As egreg puts in the comments, a true statement would be $I$ is an interval if and only if every continuous function $f:I\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is constant.

Proof. (I'm going to use notation $<a,b>$ to be an interval without distinguishing whether is open, closed or clopen.)

If $I= <a,b>$ is an interval and $f:I \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be a continuous  function. Note: for any $x,y \in R$ that $|f(x) - f(y)|$ is either $0$ or $1$.  There is no other option.

Let $m = \frac {a+b}2 \in I$.  $x$ is the mid point of $I$.  Let $f(m) = k$.  Let $K = \{x \in [<a,m]| f(x) \ne f(m)\}$.  If $K$ is non-empty, let $d = \sup K$.  Then for every neighbor of $d$ you will have a $y \le d: y \in K$ and a $w > d: w\not \in K$ so $f(y)\ne f(w)$ and $|f(y) - f(w)| = 1$ which contradicts that $f$ is continuous.  (Continuity says for $\epsilon > 0$ there is a neighborhood, $N$, of $d$ where $x,y \in N$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| <\epsilon$ which is not the case for $\epsilon \le 1$.)

So $K$ is empty.  So $f$ is constant when restricted to $<a,m]$.

A similar argument shows $f$ is constant when restricted to $[m, b>$.  So $f$ is constant on $<a,b> = I$.

If $I$ is not an interval and $I$ has two or more points, then there exists an $m \not \in I$ so that there is an $a < m$ with $a \in I$ and a $b > m$ with $b \in I$.  Let $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in I$ where $x < m$ and let $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in I$ where $x > m$.  This function is continuous and non-constant.

... because ... for any $x \in I$ and any $\epsilon > 0$.  Let $\delta = |x-m|$.  If $y \in I$ and $|x - y| < \delta$ then either $x,y$ are both less than $m$ or $x,y$ are both greater then $m$.  Either way, then $f(x) = f(y)$ and $|f(x)-f(y)| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Hmmm.... if $I$ has one point or $I$ is empty, then all functions from $I$ to $\{0,1\}$ are continuous and constant.  But single pointed sets and empty sets are trivial intervals.